# MySQL foreign key constraints throws ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Lock wait timeout) in my Rails 3.1 application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
**Software Versions:**

Rails 3.1.3
MySQL 5.5.21
OS: MacOS 10.7.3
```

Today i added a lot of foreign key constraints with the foreigner gem to my MySQL DB. 
But now i get "Lock wait timeout" exceptions on simple inserts:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Lock wait timeout exceeded; 
try restarting   transaction
```

If i remove the foreign key contraints from my DB the problem is gone.

The problem happens when i try to add an object with data for a "has_one" association with "accepts_nested_attributes_for":

```
class MyApp::PrimaryData < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :sub_data, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sub_data
    [...]
end

class MyApp::SubData < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :primary_data
    attr_accessible :field1, :field2
    [...]
end
```

---

```
table: primary_data
-------------------
- id (integer)
- field1 (string)
  [...]


table: sub_data
---------------
- id (integer)
- primary_data_id (integer)
- field1 (string)
- field2 (string)
  [...]

-> foreign_key_contraint on primary_data_id --> table primary_datas (id)
```

If I just create the "PrimaryData" without the "SubData", or the "PrimaryData" and the "SubData" separately then i get no MySQL errors, only when i am trying to create the "PrimaryData" with some "SubData" over the Rails "accepts_nested_attributes_for" way.

Does anyone can help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think i have seen this problem before but i can't quite remember in what context; it wasn't the same as the one you've described. I seem to remember i fixed my problem with a simple restart of the server and MySql. I might be wrong though…

Comment: Which engine do you use? InnoDB or MyISAM? Can you post a sample of your log when the app crash? If it's not too late of course :)

Comment: @basgys
What kind of question is that?
Foreign key checks are not supported by MyISAM.
Therefore I'm pretty sure it is InnoDB.

Answer (score -3):

This is a deadlock.

When you add a row in a table with a foreign key constraint, MySQL will acquire a lock on both this table (or row in case of InnoDB) and the referenced table (or row in case of InnoDB).

In this particular case, when you create PrimaryData with SubData, MySQL first gets a lock on primary_data, then on sub_data, and then dead locks on acquiring another lock on primary_data.

In general, using foreign keys with rails is not a good idea. Use active record validators for these purposes.

Comment: Enforcing referential integrity at the database level **as well** as at the application level is almost always a good idea. Programmers make mistakes, and getting an exception at runtime because of a **database enforced** foreign key is better than losing valuable production data due to said mistakes.

Comment: You are wrong.

Your suggestion is good in theory but not in practice. In large scale systems, you want the database to do as little work as possible, other wise you will never achieve scale.

The solution to this dilemma is to do regular database integrity checks in addition to application level integrity checks.

This also frees up your application from being coupled too closely to the particular database implementation and achieves modularity.